# What redstone machine can be used as BUD

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It is widely known that by powering a piston diagonally or two blocks above it will make it a bud. But apart from pistons, what other blocks can be used as BUDs?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A block powered diagonally or two blocks above it is commonly referred to as being BUD-powered.
Blocks that can be BUD-powered are:

- piston (both regular and sticky)
- dispenser
- dropper

When powered like that they do not react until they are updated - only then they realize they are being powered. This makes it possible to create 'block update detectors' (BUD) using these blocks.